# Android - Activity finish() results black screen

Tags: java, android, performance

I have an `AlertActivity` and an `Activity`. When a broadcast is received, both activities needs to finish. But the below code results Black screen if `AlertActivity` is on top of `Activity`.

Below is the code in `Activity`:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("BROADCAST_INTENT")){
           if(alertActvity != null)
               alertActivity.finish();
           finish();
    }
}
```

And code in `AlertActivity`:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("BROADCAST_INTENT"))
           finish();
    }
}
```

First, Activity's `onStop()` is getting called before `AlertActivity`'s `onStop()` is called which results in Black screen, even `AlertActivity`'s `finish()` called before `Activity`'s `finish()`.

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution for this:

Finishing an `Activity` with a delay of 1 second which really works. By that time, `AlertActivity` finishes and black screen cannot be displayed.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
          public void run() {
              finish();
          }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You doesn't need adding a 1 second delay, just post a runnable to the message queue also fix this bug.

Answer (score 0):

as in both `AlertActivity` and `Activity`, you are checking for same action **"BROADCAST_INTENT"**, I assume you registered both receiver in their own class.

If you did so, then actually you have two broadcast receiver waiting for same event. when this event occurs, both of your receiver are going to get it.

So in your `AlertActivity` is getting finished twice.

Comment: Yes, both receivers are in their own classes. That's where the problem is.. First `Activity` is receiving the broadcast, calls `AlertActivity` finish() -> `AlertActivity`'s `onPause()` is called -> Then `Activity`'s `finish()` is called -> Meanwhile, `AlertActivity` received broadcast -> `Activity` `onStop()`, `on Destroy()` are called -> Then `AlertActivity`'s `onStop()`,  `onDestroy()` is called.

Comment: There is about a second delay between `Activity`'s `onStop()` and `AlertActivity`'s `onStop()`

Comment: you don't need to finish() inside of AlertActivty, rather just dismiss it from Activity
if(alertActvity != null)
               alertActivity.dismiss();

Comment: i need to `finish()` inside of `AlertActivity`'s broadcast also because if  `AlertActivity` is only in foreground and receives Broadcast, then also i need to `finish()`. What do you mean by `AlertActivity.dismiss()`? Finally it will call `finish()`... Isn't it?

Comment: yes, dismiss() will eventually lead to finish(). and you shall also need to remove the broadcast receiver from AlertActivity too. your point about AlertActivity's foreground thing, it is not applicable as you can see that even if y our Activity is in the background, it's receiver is getting called. So actually it does not matter. does it?

Comment: Yes, I have removed `BroadcastReceiver` from `AlertActivity`. Even then, Blank screen is getting displayed....

Comment: change finish(); to Activity.this.finish() and make sure you are unregistering the broadcast receiver properly. –

Answer (score 0):

I think @Amit K. Saha, is right, your `AlertActivity` may be finishing twice

Solution :

If your application is running >= API 16 then you can use `finishAffinity()` method :

> Finish **this activity as well as all activities immediately below it** in the current task that have the **same affinity**. This is typically used when an application can be launched on to another task (such as from an ACTION_VIEW of a content type it understands) and the user has used the up navigation to switch out of the current task and in to its own task. In this case, if the user has navigated down into any other activities of the second application, all of those should be removed from the original task as part of the task switch.
>
> Note that this finish does not allow you to deliver results to the
>   previous activity, and an exception will be thrown if you are trying
>   to do so.

You can call `finishAffinity()` from `AlertActivity` because it is on top of `Activity`. This will finish `AlertActivity` as well as `Activity`

Comment: But the problem is `Activity` is getting finished first even before `AlertActivity` receives Broadcast. Please check my comments for Amit K. Saha answer....

Comment: Try removing `           if(alertActvity != null)
               alertActivity.finish();` code from Activity, and using `finishAffinity()`

Comment: I tried it but still blank screen is getting displayed...This is also not working buddy...

Answer (score 0):

My transparent Activity finish results black screen, after a search, i find it is caused by activity switching animation in Android 4.4. But above android 5.1 the phenomenon does not show up. 
So I add the below code:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

The black screen after finish is gone. 
I think this may be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("BROADCAST_INTENT"))
       context.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: did u try with `context.finish();`? Can u check once?